# .Net core api with AD B2C OAuth 2.0 - Invalid_token error

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-b2c

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-webapi?view=aspnetcore-2.2) resource. I can get the token successfully but get 401 upon using the token in the second call to my api. It says Bearer error='invalid_token'. Earlier it was giving "Invalid issuer" so I decoded the token to use the issuer in "Instance" field of appSettings.json. Following are appSettings and token. What am I doing wrong?

appSettings.json

```
{
"AzureAdB2C": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/v2.0/",
"ClientId": "452gfsgsdfgsdgssfs5425234",
"Domain": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
"SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_Auth-SignUpIn"
},
"Logging": {
"LogLevel": {
"Default": "Warning"
}
},
"AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

token

```
{
"iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/23423fsf234234sfsd42342vsx2542/v2.0/",
"exp": 1551878022,
"nbf": 1551874422,
"aud": "ee965664-d1e3-4144-939a-11f77c523b50",
"oid": "a9ee8ebb-433d-424b-ae24-48c73ae9969c",
"sub": "a9ee8ebb-433d-424b-ae24-48c73ae9969c",
"name": "unknown",
"extension_xxxID": "9f27fd88-7faf-e411-80e6-005056851bfe",
"emails": [
"dfgdfgadfgadfg@dgadg.com"
],
"tfp": "B2C_1_Auth-SignUpIn",
"scp": "user_impersonation",
"azp": "4453gdfgdf53535bddhdh",
"ver": "1.0",
"iat": 1551874422
}
```

AD B2C instance

[image]

Azure AD B2C setting 
[image: AD B2C]

Postman - revalapi highlighted is the uri of the registered app in the previous shot

[image]

Token

[image]

**Error**

[image]

Comment: The second call is to your own api?

Comment: Yes. I have edited the question to reflect that if it was not obvious.

Comment: When you request the access_token, the resource is also the same api?

Comment: I have used the implicit flow as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-webapi?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: @rohit I think it can resolve your problem now. If you still have any query feel free to ask. Thank you.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron : Thanks for taking time on this one. However, you have used screenshots from Azure AD and not Azure AD B2C. B2C has got a different interface as shown in my screenshot and Implicit flow is "On" and I am able to get the token successfully. I have added some more screenshots to make my problem clearer. See the last screenshot with the error.

Comment: Are you register your own API? Which subscription plan you are using?

Comment: The first screenshot shows the app which I have registered on AD B2C. And AD B2C instance is a Production-scale tenant as shown in screenshot.

Comment: @rohit You can check now, I believe this will work out nicely. If you have any more question feel free to ask.

Comment: @rohit I have figure out the case on your first problem and worked well, if is it helpful for you could mark it so it would be helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Looks like AD B2C + .Net Core is not happy with onmicrosoft.com URI even though the Microsoft docs resource say it does. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/azure-ad-b2c-webapi?view=aspnetcore-2.2). I had to use the b2clogin.com uri as shown in below screen shots. Hope it helps someone.

**Postman**

[image]

**AppSettings.json**

[image]

**Startup.Auth.cs**

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureADB2CBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options));
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();             
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For registering your [B2C dotnet core application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications#register-a-web-api) first You have to login to your B2C Tenant.

After successful Registration configure following step for implicit grant flow.

**Reply URLs**

Make sure you have done this step accordingly:

Go to Settings and add postman callback URL to : **https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback**

Once you enter this URL correctly click on Save upper left.

See the screen shot below:

[image]

**Edit Manifest**

For [implicit grand flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications#register-a-web-api) click on your application manifest and search **oauth2AllowImplicitFlow** property 
make it to  ***true***

see the screen shot below:

[image]

Your settings for azure B2C is done for [implicit grant flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow) API call.

**Postman**

Now fire up your post man and select request type as OAuth 2.0 Like below:

[image]

Now Click on Get New Access Token and new popup will appear

See the screen shot below:

***Add your tenant ID*** on Auth URL Like this :

***https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourB2CTenantId/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://graph.microsoft.com***

***Set Your Client Id***

***Set Scope you want to access***

[image]

Now click on **Request Token** In response you will get your implicit grant access token:

see the screen shot:

[image]

**Access Data With this Token:**

Copy the token you have accessed already on the Token textbox and select token type as ***Bearer Token***

See the screen shot below:

[image]

So tricky part for implicit flow is to set up manifest property **oauth2AllowImplicitFlow to true**

Hope this could solve your problem. Thank you